# django deployment issue with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, deployment, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my django project which is located at home/doga/headend/ and just to run it on the localhost (will be a LAN accessable project). My main problem is that I can use the site well however the /admin/ folder is giving me `Internal Server Error` error.

anyway here is my etc/apache2/sites-available/default file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName /
ServerAlias  */
DocumentRoot /home/doga/headend/
LogLevel warn
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/doga/headend/apache/django.wsgi
Alias /media /home/doga/headend/media/statics
Alias /admin_media /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media

</VirtualHost>
```

and here is my home/doga/headend/apache/django.wsgi file

```
import os, sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi


sys.path.append('/home/doga/')
sys.path.append('/home/doga/headend')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'headend.settings'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

lastly my main url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^headend/', include('headend.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    (r'^table/(?P<pid>.*)/$', 'main.views.table_view'),
    (r'^graph/(?P<pid>.*)/$', 'main.views.graph_view'),
    (r'^graph/$', 'main.views.platform_graph_view'),
    (r'^table/$', 'main.views.platform_view'),
    (r'^csv/$', 'main.views.csv_view'),
    (r'^recent/$', 'main.views.recent_view'),
    (r'^$', 'main.views.main_view'),
    (r'^cs/(?P<number>.*)/$', 'main.views.ch_view'),
    #(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    #(r'^$', 'main.views.main_view'),
    #(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    #   {'document_root': '/home/uluc/headendmedia/statics'}),
)
```

Comment: The values you are using for ServerName and ServerAlias directives are wrong, although that in itself shouldn't cause a problem if this is the only VirtualHost because Apache would default to using it anyway. Either way you should still fix it. As someone else said, you shouldn't set DocumentRoot to be where your Django site is. Plus important to see the actual messages from Apache error log so can see what is generating that error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you should be setting the `DocumentRoot` to `/home/doga/headend`. Won't this give access to all your source code?

What detail does the Apache log give for the Internal Server Error?